# python async library issue

Tags: python, asynchronous, async-await, python-asyncio

I have the following script, but it work incorecctly. I want to first function always repeat and second function should start if first function return result1, result2. I want to add one more function which should start 40 seconds after second function finished job with result1 from first function. Third function should do something with result2. I want to work it asynchronously using asyncio library because i need the first function to not block for 40 seconds while third function sleep. I tried to use chatgpt, but this tool recommend me wrong things. How to do that?

```
import asyncio
import logging



async def first_function(queue1, queue2):
    while True:
        # do something
        result1 = "some result"
        result2 = {"key": "value"}
        await queue1.put(result1)
        await queue2.put(result2)
        await asyncio.sleep(1)  # wait for 1 second

async def second_function(queue1, queue2, queue3):
    while True:

           result1 = await queue1.get()
           result2 = await queue2.get()
           # do something with the results
           logging.info(f"Second function received: {result1}, {result2}")
           await queue3.put(result1)
           await asyncio.sleep(1)  # wait for 1 second


async def third_function(queue):
    while True:

           result = await queue.get()
           await asyncio.sleep(40) # wait for 40 seconds
           # do something with the result
           logging.info(f"Third function received: {result}")


async def main():
    queue1 = asyncio.Queue()
    queue2 = asyncio.Queue()
    queue3 = asyncio.Queue()
    task1 = asyncio.create_task(first_function(queue1, queue2))
    task2 = asyncio.create_task(second_function(queue1, queue2, queue3))
    task3 = asyncio.create_task(third_function(queue3))
    await asyncio.gather(task1, task2, task3)
```

I tried everything i googled and it always block my code for 40 seconds when reach third function

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is multiple issues and anti-patterns:

- there is no need to use `asyncio.create_task()` since AsyncIO will do that automatically for you when the objects are coroutines,
- you use unbounded queues, which means that the memory consumption or your program could grow unlimited,
- `third_function` takes 40 seconds while `first_function` produces elements every 12 seconds which means that the former won't have time to process elements fast enough,
- if `result1` and `result_2` should be produces at the same time and consumed at the same time, use a single queue to put both elements.

You could use something like this:

```py
import asyncio


async def first_function(queue_in: asyncio.Queue):
    while True:
        result1 = "some result"
        result2 = {"key": "value"}
        await queue_in.put((result1, result2))


async def second_function(queue_in: asyncio.Queue, queue_out: asyncio.Queue):
    while True:
        result1, result2 = await queue_in.get()
        print(f"Second function received: {result1}, {result2}")
        await queue_out.put(result1)


async def third_function(queue_out: asyncio.Queue):
    while True:
        result = await queue_out.get()
        await asyncio.sleep(4)
        print(f"Third function received: {result}")


async def main():
    queue_in = asyncio.Queue(maxsize=1)
    queue_out = asyncio.Queue(maxsize=1)
    
    task1 = first_function(queue_in)
    task2 = second_function(queue_in, queue_out)
    task3 = third_function(queue_out)
    
    await asyncio.gather(task1, task2, task3)
    
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

By specifying `maxsize=1` you limit the production of `first_function` because now `third_function` defines the consumption rate: `first_function` (and `second_function` to) is only allowed to produce a new element when `third_function` finished processing the last one.

If you cannot control the rate at which `first_function` produces elements, you should implement a back-pressure strategy where for instance you drop elements if you cannot process them fast enough. You can use a higher value for `max size` if you want to allow some sort of `waiting` before elements are dropped.

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply! You are right about asyncio.create_task(), i get it and this solution fix my problem
About queue, maybe i don't understand something but i can't put several results in one queue because it give me error. For me it works like 
total_result = result1, result2, await queue_in.put((total_result))
I stayed with my 3 queue becaue it works too) is it bad to use a lot of queues?
Also i didn't get what is the point to set the limit on queue? I thought if will be more results from first function at close time it just run several second and third function asyncronously isn't it?

Comment: No, it is not wrong to use multiple/many queues if it suits your needs. The queue size limit is very important and should not be neglected of you want to build a robust system. If you limit a queue to `N` items, then `await queue.put(item)` will block (wait) if the queue is full.

Comment: If my answer helped you, consider upvoting/accepting it please.